# byte external allocation too large for this process", "VM won't let us allocate bytes"

Tags: android, memory-management, logcat, dalvik

I'm using Android 2.2 and, when I'm trying to return from second activity to first activity by pressing a back button, the app crashes and produces a logcat error:

```
byte external allocation too large for this process,
    VM won't let us allocate bytes
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are running out-of-memory, so the activity cannot reinit.
Please check this link for tracking you memory in Android - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

However, if you'll paste some more logs and code - it can help to determine exact problem.

Good luck